# User defined global hotkeys

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hotkeys, user-defined

I am coding an application in **WinForms (C#, .NET 4.0)**. I know how to use global **hotkeys** using Pinvoke. I am also able to define the set of hotkeys like `CRLT+M` etc etc.
But, I want that at runtime, user can set it's own **hotkeys** as most of the software provides. Here I stuck. **How can I provide the user the feature to select the hotkey combination and how can I handle it?**

Thanks